# how to select max xml attribute based on its attribute value start with “pro_” in xslt?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a weird requirement to get the max value that starts with specified string.Below is my [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) sample source code,As we have seen the **book** element has an attribute called **id**,as we have seen,some value of the **id** attribute are start with "pro_",such as **pro_60**,**pro_55**,while the other attribute value are just pure number,such as **70**,**40**.

*So my question is how to get the attribute value that starts with **pro_** and the number is the max number*.In this example the max number starts with **pro_** is **65**,so the expected result is **pro_65**,I can do it in my [java](/questions/tagged/java) code ,but I am wondering **can we do it just by using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)**?Any help is very greatful!

**XPath version is 1.0**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <datas>
    <books>
        <book id="pro_60">Java</book>
        <book id="pro_55">Golang</book>
        <book id="pro_40">PHP</book>
        <book id="pro_65">C++</book>
        <book id="pro_55">Python</book>
        <book id="70">Javascript</book>
        <book id="40">HTML5</book>
    </books>
</datas>
```

Comment: Well which version of XPath can you use? We have XPath 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 by now and each new version is more expressive than the older ones. XPath 2.0 has a `max` function, XPath 3.0 adds a `let` expression, so that way it is doable in a succinct way.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using **dom4j 1.6**,and the xpath version is 1.0,thank you

Comment: Which is the value you want returned, the full attribute value (e.g. `pro_65`) or only the number part of that attribute value (e.g. `65`)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen only the number, after searching the internet I found it's impossible by using xpath 1.0.So I changed my requirement,  I am wondering can we use xpath1.0 to get all the attribute values that starts with "pro_" ,I am using **substring(/datas/books/book/@id[starts-with(.,'pro_')],4)**,but it only returns the first result

Comment: `/datas/books/book/@id[starts-with(.,'pro_')]` would give you all the attribute nodes. You cannot call substring on all of them in XPath 1.0, instead in XPath 1.0 your attempt `substring(/datas/books/book/@id[starts-with(.,'pro_')],4)` does what most string functions do when the argument is a node set of more than one node, the function is applied to the first node in the node set. With XPath 2.0 you would get an error if there is more than one node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A shorter XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
max(/*/*/*/@id[starts-with(.,'pro_')]/number(substring(.,5)))
```

This just calculates the maximum value.

**To select all elements with `id` attributes that have this maximum value, use**:

```
(/*/*/*[@id = concat('pro_', string(max(/*/*/*/@id[starts-with(.,'pro_')]/number(substring(.,5)))))]
```

As for XPath 1.0, this cannot be computed using a single XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: I am using xpath in [tag:dom4j] 1.6 to parse the content,since [tag:dom4j] 1.6 is only support xpath1.0, so xoath1.0 is not avaiable for me. Now I am wondering can we use xpath1.0 to get all the attribute values that starts with "pro_",I am using **substring(/datas/books/book/@id[starts-with(.,'pro_')],4)**,but in only returns the first result.

Comment: @lucumt, As said in this answer, the wanted result cannot be produced by evaluating a single XPath 1.0 expression. Using your programming language, you can evaluate an XPath 1.0 expression (in a loop) that gets you all wanted numbers. Then, again using your programming language, you can find the wanted maximum.

Comment: A masterful construction!   Do explain, please, the step where `/number()` is applied to the list of `pro_` `@id`s.  This `/` is obviously not the usual abbreviation for the child axis.

Comment: @kjhughes, In XPath 2.0 and next versions, the right argument of the last location step is allowed to be a function call. See rules [27], [38], and [41], at: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-grammar

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath 2.0:

```
/datas/books/book/@id[starts-with(., 'pro_')][not(../../book/@id/number(substring-after(., 'pro_')) > number(substring-after(., 'pro_')))]
```

As it depends on the feature of using functions calls in the last step of a path to compute a sequence of atomic values it can not be directly translated to XPath 1.0.

Comment: Martin, why such a long expression? A more than twice-shorter one exists :)

Comment: Well in the question it says "so the expected result is pro_65" so I tried to select the node with that value and not the maximum value `65` itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I added the full XPath 2.0 expression now.